# Database not storing JSON variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-models, gridster

I have an django app in which I am trying to store the gridster widget configuration in the form of JSON variable to database.But when I click"Update" button on my webpage my database does not stores any value.

My JS Code which sends serial value to database

```
var gridster;
 var $color_picker = $('#color_picker');
 var URL = "{% url 'save-grid' %}";


gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
  widget_base_dimensions: [80, 80],
  widget_margins: [5, 5],
  helper: 'clone',
  resize: {
    enabled: true
  }
}).data('gridster');


$(".add-button").on("click", function() {

   $('#test').click();

  $('#test').on('change', function(e) {
    var test = document.getElementById('test');

    if (!test) {
      alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
    }
    else if (!test.files) {
      alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
    }
    else if (!test.files[0]) {
      alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");               
    }
    else {
      file = test.files[0];
      console.log(file);
      fr = new FileReader();
      fr.readAsDataURL(file); 
      fr.onload = function() {
        var data = fr.result;  // data <-- in this var you have the file data in Base64 format
        callbackAddButton(data);
        test.value = '';
        $('#test').replaceWith($('#test').clone())

      };
    }
  })
});

function callbackAddButton(file) {
 // get selected color value
  var color = $color_picker.val();

  // build the widget, including a class for the selected color value
  var $widget = $('<li>', {
      'class': 'color_' + color
    })
    .append($('<button>', {
      'class': 'delete-button',
      'text':'-'
    }))
   .append($(`<img src="${file}" height="60px" width="60px">`));

  // add widget to the grid
  gridster.add_widget($widget, 1, 1);
}




  $('.js-seralize-update').on('click', function () {

            var s = gridster.serialize();
            updated_grid=JSON.stringify(s);
            $('#log').val(updated_grid);

            function updategridster(){
            var data = updated_grid;
            $.post(URL, data, function(response){
            if(response === 'success'){ alert('Yay!'); }
            else{ alert('Error! :('); }
    });
}

        });

$('.gridster').on("click", ".delete-button", function() {
  gridster.remove_widget($(this).parent());

  });




var serialization = updated_grid
serialization = Gridster.sort_by_row_and_col_asc(serialization);


 $('.js-seralize-restore').on('click', function () {
            gridster.remove_all_widgets();
            $.each(serialization, function () {
                gridster.add_widget('<li />', this.size_x, this.size_y, this.col, this.row);
            });

   });
```

My urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'myapp/save-grid$', views.save_grid, name='save-grid'),

    ]
```

My views.py

```
    from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
    from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
    from django.http import HttpResponse

    from os import path

    from .models import  update_grid
def save_grid(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            grid = update_grid(data=data)
            grid.save()
            return HttpResponse('success') # if everything is OK
```

My Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from jsonfield import JSONField
class update_grid(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    data = JSONField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am able to add JSON variable through admin.But nof able to get where I am making mistake

I am just not sure about my javascript part.Whether I have written passing of variable to django syntactically correct

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9gnembfg/1/)

**Edit 1**

My JS Script is updated as follows

```
  var URL = "{% url 'save-grid' %}";

     $('.js-seralize-update').on('click', function () {

                var s = gridster.serialize();
                updated_grid=JSON.stringify(s);
                $('#log').val(updated_grid);

                function updategridster(updated_grid){
                var data = updated_grid;
                $.post(URL, data, function(response){
                if(response === 'success'){ alert('Yay!'); }
                else{ alert('Error! :('); }
        });
    }
                 updategridster(updated_grid);          
            });
```

Now I get this error

```
 POST http://localhost:8000/calendar_grid/save-grid net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED  jquery.min.js:2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you are reading the data in Django since request.body returns a byte string

Try replacing this javascript line

```
var data = updated_grid;
```

with

```
var data = {json: updated_grid}
```

Then in your django view access it via request.POST like this

```
def save_grid(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            json_data = request.POST.get('json')
            print(json_data) # Can add a print here for testing
            data = json.loads(json_data)
            grid = update_grid.objects.create(data=data, title='title')
            return HttpResponse('success') # if everything is OK
```

Also if you have errors with the csrf_token this is helpful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: Should it be   `data = json.loads(json_data)`

Comment: I get these errors  `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`   and   `myapp.views.save_grid didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: Yep should be json_data there. Also in the javascript json shouldnt be in quotes. Edited my answer

Comment: The way I have declared the URL is it correct `URL = "{% url 'save-grid' %}";` This then points to my urls.py

Comment: I still get same error mentioned in comment number 2